# jwplayer IE and Safari - Video plays only audio

Tags: html, video, jwplayer

I have problems playing videos with jwplayer in IE and Safari. 
In this two browsers (testet in IE10 and Safari 5.1.7) the embeded video plays only the audio.

I embeded the jwplayer this way:

```
<div id="jwplayer-video">
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width: 80px;">
     <div class="bar" style="width: 80%;"></div>
</div>
<b>&nbsp; &nbsp; Video wird geladen ...</b>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("jwplayer-video").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg", 
        sources: [{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.webm",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.flv",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.mp4",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.ogv",
        }]
    }]
});
</script>
```

You can find a example here: http://physio-visor.at/test.html

I hope you have a solution for me ...

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: Hi no sorry - isn't possible, because it's in a paid members area. SORRY!

Comment: OK now I have created a testsite, where you can test the video:
http://physio-visor.at/test.html

Comment: On your test site it won't play the video MP4 file, but the other formats play. How did you encode your MP4?

Comment: I convert .mov videos with the software "Any Video Converter" to "HTML5 MP4 Film". Then I choose "Original Size" as video-size and as Video Codec I chosse x264 (no other possibility) and as Video Bitrate I chosse 768 and as Framerate: 30.

Comment: Now I'm a step closer to the solution:
I converted the video with another converter to mp4. And now the video also plays in Safari. 
BUT in IE now the player can't find a playable source ... :(

Comment: I would try using this tool to encode - http://handbrake.fr/, another thing you can try is to force flash by setting the player's primary variable to flash, that might resolve the IE issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! handbrake.fr made it! I convertet the .mov file with handbrake.fr to mp4. and now IE also plays the video. 
PERFECT!!!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working, np!!!!